# How to get gcc3.2 nowadays?

Tags: c++, gcc

I want to build some old source code which has to be compiled with gcc3.2. I was using CentOS. I tried to find a pre-built binary for gcc3.2, but I didn't. Then I try to build gcc3.2 from source code. But the lowest version of gcc I got on my hand is 4.8.5, and when I used it to compile gcc3.2 some errors also encountered. Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: You could update the code so that it becomes build able with a modern compiler. You'd probably be fixing a ton of bugs in the process.

Comment: Maybe install some old distro on virtual machine?

Comment: I'm surprised to see it can only compile with a specific version of GCC, have you tried changing the c++ standard it used? (-std=c++98)